# Create voxels from a sphere pack and store as boolean

Tags: voxel

I'm trying to convert my output file from my matlab code that has an output of position vectors and sphere radius. I intend to create voxels from these spheres and store in boolean form i.e 1 for sphere, 0 for void. Please how do you advise I go about this. Here's an  example of the output.

```
Pos (x) ,       Pos (y),        Pos (z)        Radius

    -0.34316     -0.18477     -0.00897   0.0900
    -0.18425     -0.20463      0.08040   0.020
    -0.46883     -0.49809      0.36954   0.020
     0.24727     -0.19437     -0.28274   0.0876
     0.39771      0.49293     -0.49469   0.0200
    -0.04368      0.26251     -0.07504   0.0200
    -0.34705      0.04092      0.37070   0.0200
```

Here's a snippet of the matlab code I'm working with. The spheres are originally in a lattice space.Thanks

```
coords=zeros(N,3); % list of the 3D positions of all particles

overlap=(6*phi/(pi*N))^(1/3);

% create initial, evenly-spaced lattice
numcell=(ceil(N^(1/3)));

cellside=1/numcell;

hh=linspace(-.5+.5*cellside,.5-.5*cellside,numcell);

for ii=1:N

coords(ii,1)=hh(ceil(ii/ceil(N/numcell)));

coords(ii,2)=hh(floor(mod(ii,ceil(N/numcell))/numcell)+1);

coords(ii,3)=hh(mod(ii,numcell)+1);

end                               
scatter3(coords(:,1),coords(:,2),coords(:,3),'filled');
```

Comment: Please provide more information on what the voxel intensities should look like with sample data.

Comment: Where is the matlab code?